# XAMPP: Your /etc/hosts is not okay. I will fix it

Tags: apache, terminal, xampp, webserver, lampp

I'm getting this error on starting my apache. I'm using linux server. Can somebody help me. Thank you!

```
XAMPP: Starting Apache...fail.
XAMPP:  Starting diagnose... 
XAMPP: Your /etc/hosts is not okay. I will fix it.
XAMPP:  Next try...
XAMPP: Starting Apache...fail.
XAMPP:  Starting diagnose... 
XAMPP: Your /etc/hosts is not okay. I will fix it.
XAMPP:  Next try...
XAMPP: Starting Apache...fail.
XAMPP:  Starting diagnose... 
XAMPP: Your /etc/hosts is not okay. I will fix it.
XAMPP:  Next try...
XAMPP: Starting Apache...fail.
XAMPP:  Starting diagnose... 
XAMPP: Your /etc/hosts is not okay. I will fix it.
XAMPP:  Next try...
XAMPP: Starting Apache...fail.
```

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: I just reinstall everything.

Comment: I did manage to fix mine without reinstalling. It was caused by wrong paths to certificates in the SSL configuration, I basically opened the SSL config file, commented out everything and started un-commenting line by line until I get the error and investigate / fix the issue.

Comment: @ Tony Bogdanov: Absolutely right. Your 3 lines answer saved me. Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

it just happened, because i disabled ssl in httpd-ssl.conf, when i re-enabled it all worked fine again

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had a virtual host which had SSLEngine On. I actually did not need this. Try disabling, if you happen to have one.

```
#<VirtualHost *:443>
#   ServerAdmin admin@vaayushop.com
#    DocumentRoot "/opt/lampp/docs/api.server1.vaayushop.com"
#
#    SSLEngine on
    #SSLCertificateFile  <Path to my certificate file>
    #SSLCertificateKeyFile <Path to my certificate file>
#</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I fix the problem as explain the mate Tony Bogdanov:

"I did manage to fix mine without reinstalling. It was caused by wrong paths to certificates in the SSL configuration, I basically opened the SSL config file, commented out everything and started un-commenting line by line until I get the error and investigate / fix the issue. –"

Regards.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please refer to [How do I write a good Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for tips how to improve your contribution.